# How do you synchronize the id of a java object to its associated db row?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How do you synchronize the id of a java object to its associated db row after you've called `entityManager.persist(object);`

and committed the transaction?
If you are using any strategy by which the db sets the id, you need to get that id from the db and set it on object if you want to use object in future queries. This:

```
entityManager.refresh(object);
```

does not work, because it uses the id to query for object, and that's what's missing.
The only thing I can think of doing is querying the db for object on its unique attributes and then setting the id on object.

Maybe there's a best practice for id generation that solves this I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`persist()` makes instance managed, which means the `id` would be there after calling `persist()`, **when the transaction is committed**. You can check it by doing this,

```
System.out.println(someEntity.getId()); // null at this point of time
em.persist(someEntity)
System.out.println(someEntity.getId()); // should print the id
```

Comment: Ah, close! someEntity.id is not set after the call to persist(). But it is set after the transaction is committed.

Comment: @Chance: Thanks for making it explicit, it will also help in avoiding similar misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

persist modifies the persisted object if the id strategy is one that is generated by the database like a sequence, then the id will be set in the persisted object.

Comment: Ah, so it does.  Thanks Chance.  I assumed it returned the entity because that's what I'm doing in my dao implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't let the database autogenerate my ID's.  Instead I use random 128 bit numbers and set them myself during initial object creation inside my application layer.  I store them in VARBINARY(16) or preferably BINARY(16) if my database engine supports it.

I don't know the exact answer as it relates to Hibernate, but if you want to get auto-generated ID's back to you, this link might provide a few leads:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)

In particular notice the 2nd parameter:

```
Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
```

Presumably there is some way to get Hibernate to call that 2nd parameter with the value of Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS !