# ID of java objects not synchronizing with database

Tags: java, jpa

The only link I found that's close to what I am experiencing is this one :
[How do you synchronize the id of a java object to its associated db row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654506/how-do-you-synchronize-the-id-of-a-java-object-to-its-associated-db-row?newreg=f0aff7f4936140d0a331386ab884ec90)
and there's not much of a solution in it.

My problem is that my Java objects aren't updated after being added to my database despite the .commit()

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    System.out.println(eleve.getID());
    em.persist(eleve);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println(eleve.getID());
```

which refers to this class

```
public class Eleve {

private String _nom;
private String _prenom;
private float _ptsMerite;
@Id
private int _IDEleve;
```

and yields this output :
0
0

I think I've done everything properly when it comes to the persistence since it does create the object in the database (mySQL) with correct ID's which I've set to be autoincrement.
I am using javax.persistence for everything (annotations and such).

Comment: You have an int _IDEleve marked as the ID for the entity, but not shown how you set that value; basically you've just told JPA to insert a row with an ID value of 0, so its done that and cached the object as ID=0. If you are going to use DB identity or triggers to set the value, you need to tell JPA about it so that it knows 0 isn't the actual entity ID value, and so it knows how to go about looking it up (either after, or even before) aka sequencing. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

Comment: @Chris this comment looks a lot like an answer, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation at your ID field?

There are four possible strategies you can choose from:

- `GenerationType.AUTO`: The JPA provider will choose an appropriate strategy for the underlying database.
- `GenerationType.IDENTITY`: Relies on a auto-increment column in your database.
- `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`: Relies on a database sequence
- `GenerationType.TABLE`: Uses a generator table in the database.

More info: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-strategies-when-set-primary-key

If you ever change to a more powerful framework it is likely that this manages your transactions (CMT) so you can't (or don't want) commit everytime you want to access the ID for a new entity. In these cases you can use `EntityManager#flush` to synchronize Entity Manager with database.

Comment: Perfect, this is what i needed. I asked a friend who advised AUTO which generated errors but the IDENTITY worked like a charm. Thank you for listing the different types.